# Usar Blender 3D para criar jogos para Android

Tags: android, blender

Boas, alguém sabe se é possível usar o Blender 3D para criar jogos para Android, e programá-los através do Android Studio?

Comment: Que eu saiba Blender é so para modelagem. Você usaria apenas os modelos para fazer seu jogo com o Android Studio.

Comment: @Marco Marques sim era isso que eu queria saber..  Se dá para usar os modelos na aplicação android.  Sei que com Unity é possivel,  mas e no Android Studio?

Comment: Pelo que li depois de ver sua pergunta, é sim possível importar objetos 3D para o Android Studio. Mas ao que tudo indica, o Android Studio não é uma ferramenta própria para a criação de jogos que não sejam muito simples (jogo da velha, campo mina) existem ferramentas muito melhores para isso.

Fazendo uma analogia: Usar o Android Studio para criar um jogo (seja ele de plataforma, corrida, luta), é como fazer uma bola de futebol com uma chave de fenda. Você vai conseguir, mas vai demorar MUUUUUUUUITO.

Answer (score 1):

Dá sim, você cria seus modelos e os importa pro Android Studio.
Olha ai uns exemplos: http://download.blender.org/demo/android/